# Plotly: How to handle varying text sizes in a stacked funnel plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm attempting to produce a stacked funnel plot of activities. The labels are not appearing as expected on the plot.

First my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

stages = ["Initial Landing", "Step 2", "Step 3", "Added to cart", "Purchased"]
regiona_plotly = pd.DataFrame(dict(number=[10866,10543,1067,1032,108], stage=stages))
regionb_plotly = pd.DataFrame(dict(number=[10650,10432,1076,1036,1012], stage=stages))
regiona_plotly['region'] = "Region A"
regionb_plotly['region'] = "Region B"
df = pd.concat([regiona_plotly, regionb_plotly], axis=0)
fig = px.funnel(df, x='number', y='stage', color='region')
fig.update_traces(textposition='auto')
fig.update_layout(autosize=True)
fig.write_image("region_funnel.png")
```

(Lifted almost entirely from [plotly documents](https://plotly.com/python/funnel-charts/))

This code produces an image like so:
[image: Plotly - Auto Text Position]

Notice that on "Step 3", "Added to cart", and "Purchased" the region A text is scaled very small  and inside the bar, but Region B is outside.

I tried updating this line:

```
fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
```

But, with this, I get both values overlapping on the Region B side of the funnel. Also, the text goes outside of the plot on the upper bands.

[image: Plotly - Outside Text Position]

**How can I get text to be the same size and either be within the bar if it fits at the size or outside and on the correct side, if it doesn't?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

This seems to be a bug. If what you need is a `.png` image of your figure, run:

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='funnel.html')
```

And then produce a `.png` version using the user interface camera icon:

[image]

#### Result:

[image]

---

#### The details:

This is a strange one. And quite possibly a bug that would be of interest to the plotly community forum. I have a work-around though. Assuming that what you would in fact like to end up with here is a `.png` image file of your plot.

If you run your exact code in JupyterLab, but exchange the line `fig.write_image("region_funnel.png")` with just `fig.show()`, you'll get this:

[image]

No small text there! And if I understand correctly, a figure without varying text size would be a satisfactory solution? But `fig.show()` creates a html object, and not a `.png`  image. So I tested the available output options for `fig.write_image()` which are:

- 'png'
- 'jpg' or 'jpeg'
- 'webp'
- 'svg'
- 'pdf'
- 'eps' (Requires the poppler library to be installed)

I ruled out `webp` and `eps` as viable solutions and tested the rest of them. And each and every one produced the same undeseried varying text sizes. Even producing a figure using `fig.show()` in JupyterLab and then manually downloading a file using the user interface camera icon produced the very same results *even though* the html version looked fine.

***But*** if you run:

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='funnel.html')
```

And ***then*** download a `.png` version you'll get this:

[image]

Which should be a viable option for you if I understand correctly. Admittedly, this is far from a perfect answer, but I hope you'll find it useful all the same.